# Continuous execution of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `function` that handles clicks when certain condition is met.

**Scenario:**

I want to close automatically the modal when click the Sign In button only if certain condition is met. And that condition is inside the `$scope.empSignin()`.

So what I did according to some sources in the google, I create a `function` that will handle `click` event when the condition is valid.

**html**

```
//$scope.closeModal function
<button id="closeModal" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="closeModal()">&times;</button>

//$scope.empSignin function
<input type="button" value="Sign In" ng-click="empSignin(signinInfo)">
```

this is the `html` file that contains a `button` that is automatically clicked in `js function`.

**file.js**

```
$scope.closeModal = function(){
    console.log('entered');
    $timeout(function(){
        var el = document.getElementById('closeModal');
        angular.element(el).trigger('click');
    }, 0);   
}

$scope.empSignin = function(signinInfo){
    var data = {
        username : signinInfo.username,
        password : signinInfo.password
    }
    $http.post('server/emp_signin.php', data).then(function(res){
        window.alert(res.data.message);
        $scope.isMessage = res.data.message;
        if($scope.isMessage == 'Successfully Signed In'){
            console.log('true');
            $scope.closeModal();
        } else { console.log('false'); }

    });
}
```

this `js file` contains `function` that handles click event.

It is working as I expected but when that event happened, in browsers `console` there is continuous execution (for what I know).

My question is what is happening there and why is that? And how I can solve that issue cause it is taking plenty of my device resources when I view in taskmanager.

**Here is the screenshot of console:**

[image: browsers console image]

Comment: This is not how Angular works. You don't select elements by ID in Angular. Besides, why would you select an element, then simulate a click on it, instead of simply calling the `closeModal()` function?

Comment: Because of you write code in settimeout zero that's why

Comment: @Jinesh, settimeout will add only a delay in execution, it will not set the code to be executed more than one time.

Comment: @JeremyThille, I am sorry for not understanding really of the Angular way. It seems that I need to think of better solution.

Comment: @Marksmanship, did you try the solution I gave in my answer?

Comment: you can use e1.trigger('click');

Comment: @Jinesh No. You don't select elements and trigger clicks, not in Angular. Angular _generates_ the DOM and the elements, so it makes no sense making it generate them, then select them and simulate clicks. Just trigger the function you want to trigger.

Comment: @JeremyThille, thanks for knowledgeable comment of yours. Honestly, I can't think of a way of how can I trigger the close button of the modal when the POST method returns an valid response.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are calling `closeModal` function on click event of the `<button>` and in the function, you are triggering `click` event again and which again calls `closeModal` function and thus it goes to infinite loop.And so you are seeing `entered` text in your console so many times. That's the issue.

```
angular.element(el).trigger('click'); // This is putting your code in infinite execution.
```

So remove above-mentioned line and there won't be the continuous execution of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not working.
I updated my question added another relevant `function`.

Comment: @Marksmanship, the new function you added is not being called from anywhere or its not linked with any tag.